# Curve fit in a log-log plot in matplotlib and getting the equation of line

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, linear-regression, curve-fitting

I am trying to draw a best fit curve for my data. It is terribly bad sample of data, but for simplicity's sake let's say, I expect to draw a straight line as a best fit in log-log scale.

I think I already did that with regression and it returns me a reasonable fit line. But I want to double check it with curve fit function in scipy. And I also want to extract the equation of the fit line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.optimize as optimization




x = np.array([ 1.72724547e-08,   1.81960233e-08,   1.68093027e-08,   2.22839973e-08,
   2.23090589e-08,   4.28020801e-08,   2.30004711e-08,   2.48543008e-08,
1.08633065e-07,   3.24417303e-08,   3.22946248e-08,   3.82328031e-08,
   3.97713860e-08,   3.44080732e-08,   3.81526816e-08,   3.30756706e-08
])

y = np.array([ 4.18793565e+12,   4.40554864e+12,   4.48745390e+12,   4.50816705e+12,
   4.57088190e+12,   4.60256574e+12,   4.66659380e+12,   4.79733449e+12,  7.31139083e+12,   7.53355564e+12,   8.03526122e+12,   8.14704284e+12,
   8.47227414e+12,   8.62978548e+12,   8.81048873e+12,   9.46237161e+12
 ])


# Regression Function
def regress(x, y):
    """Return a tuple of predicted y values and parameters for linear regression."""
    p = sp.stats.linregress(x, y)
    b1, b0, r, p_val, stderr = p
    y_pred = sp.polyval([b1, b0], x)
    return y_pred, p

# plotting z
allx, ally = x, y                              # data, non-transformed
y_pred, _ = regress(np.log(allx), np.log(ally))      # change here           # transformed input             

plt.loglog(allx, ally, marker='$\\star$',color ='g', markersize=5,linestyle='None')
plt.loglog(allx, np.exp(y_pred), "c--", label="regression")  # transformed output



# Let's fit an exponential function.  
# This looks like a line on a lof-log plot.
def myExpFunc(x, a, b):
    return a * np.power(x, b)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(myExpFunc, x, y, maxfev=1000)
plt.plot(x, myExpFunc(x, *popt), 'r:', 
         label="({0:.3f}*x**{1:.3f})".format(*popt))
print "Exponential Fit: y = (a*(x**b))"
print "\ta = popt[0] = {0}\n\tb = popt[1] = {1}".format(*popt)

plt.show()
```

Again I apologize for a bad dataset. your help will be very appreciated.

My plot looks like this:
[image]
    enter code here

Comment: What exactly is the problem you experience?

Comment: curve_fit function from scipy is not working, that red dotted line should coincide with cyan line. Cyan line comes from sp.stats.linregress

Comment: Are you sure you dont want to call `plt.plot(x, myExpFunc(x, *popt))`?

Comment: nice catch, now that I made the correction, my curve fit red line seems parallel, but way off of my regression curve? Any idea why that is happening? I updated my image.

Comment: I suggest looking at a non-log scatterplot of the raw data, when I do this it looks to me as if log scales are unnessecary and a non-log straight line fit is about the best you might do with the data set in your posted code.

Comment: Hi James, this is a subset of my research data. and I specifically need a logarithmic fit for this. I am still wondering if linear regression can make a god fit for the data, why cannot I check it with some other functions, like curve_fit from scipy?

Comment: Please post a link to the entire data set.